# Trying to compare items from list A with items from list B and then returning a third list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I searched the internet for an answer but, I can't seem to make the solutions work. I am trying to compare items from lists using nested loops (for an exercise). Every time an item from list `A (num_list)` is bigger then list `B (value_list)`, I want the counter to go up and eventually return a list with the counter divided by some stuff.
Currently, the error I am getting is that:

> a bool object is not iterable.

After some adjustments, I got:

> index is out of range

even though I defined it as the range of the longest list. I don't know why the code isn't working, so I would love help!
Thank you!!

```
for i in num_list:
    for j in value_list in range(1, len(num_list)):
        counter = 0
        while value_list[j] >= num_list[i]:
            counter += 1
        result = counter / len(num_list)
        distribution.append(result)
```

Comment: Your `i` is an element of `num_list`, not its index. If you want the index as well, have a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate). You can run small programs for instance in [Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to see, if the actual values are in agreement with the expected values.

Comment: this `while value_list[j] >= num_list[i]: counter += 1`  is an endless loop - you are not changing anything that would change the `while` - condition so it will either not enter or never leave ... Hotel California anybody?

Comment: Thank you Mr. T! will look at what you said!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistake values with indexes and got an possible endless while loop in your code.

```
while value_list[j] >= num_list[i]: 
    counter += 1
```

you are not changing anything that would change the `while` - condition so it will either not enter or never leave.

Your code fixed:

```
nums= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
vals= [-1,0,2,5,7,99]
dist = []
for i in nums:      # no need to index into lists, simply use the values
    counter = 0
    for j in vals:
        if i < j:
            counter += 1
    result = counter / len(nums)
    distribution.append(result)

print(dist) # [0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]
```

---

You can solve your issue by creating sublists that only take from `vals` if the value is bigger/equal then your current `n`:

```
nums= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
vals= [-1,0,2,5,7,99]

result = []

for n in nums:
    result.append((n, [x for x in vals if x >= n]) ) #add a tuple of (n, [bigger values])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, [2, 5, 7, 99]), (2, [2, 5, 7, 99]), (3, [5, 7, 99]), 
 (4, [5, 7, 99]),    (5, [5, 7, 99]),    (6, [7, 99])]
```

and operate on that:

```
l = len(nums)
# calculate each lists length / length of nums
k = [ len(x[1]) / l for x in result]
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[0.6666666666666666, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Comment: @Omri.B If this anwer solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)